# Issue installing bower in windows7 32 bit on a specified folder

Tags: node.js, git, npm, bower

I was trying to install bower on windows 7 32 bit. But whenever I am running npm install -g bower on comand prompt, it is not installing on my specified folder path.

The code is as follows....

```
C:\Work\BowerExample>npm install -g bower
C:\Users\Sunanda\AppData\Roaming\npm\bower -> C:\Users\Sunanda\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\bin\bower
C:\Users\Sunanda\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

`-- bower@1.8.0

What could be wrong?

NOTE:  C:\Program Files\Git\cmd; C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Users\Sunanda\AppData\Roaming\npm is already added to my path environment variable

Comment: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd; C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Users\Sunanda\AppData\Roaming\npm is already added to my path environment variable.

Comment: If you are use `npm install -g bower` it will install bower in global so run `npm install bower`.

Comment: I have already tried this..but the result remains same.